# Alternative to a financial planner?

Tags: united-states, financial-advisor

Are there any good websites or resources for sharing a personal financial plan? I think I've done enough personal research to be fairly confident in what I'm doing, but a second set of eyes would be reassuring.

Or if not personal plans, maybe vetted templates or methods?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question Aaron. I have a few suggestions:

**Dave Ramsey**

Are you familiar with Dave Ramsey's Financial Peace or Total Money Makeover programs?
Each of these has a large online community, and most likely there are people who either teach or participate in these courses at your local church/civic center, etc who could work with you. You could Google for local resources or a number of online forums.

You should be aware that these programs are organized around a central set of financial principles that not everyone agrees with. It's likely that if your plan varies considerably from those ideas, you might not get full support from that community. However, these programs are both comprehensive and very well organized, and will walk you through what they think you should do in a prioritized order, and also how to go about it (how to budget for different things, what percent of income are typically spent on different categories, recommended investment plans, etc.) and may be useful to you even if you don't fully buy in to the principles.

**Right Here!**

This forum is a great place to ask for personal financial advice, and would probably be best able to help by reviewing general aspects of your plan. For example, you could say what you're planning to do and ask for feedback. However, it is important to understand that users here will provide their personal opinions based on our own experience, and you're likely to get a variety of different responses.

**Online Resources**

If by "financial plan" you mean mostly investments rather than budgeting/emergency fund/etc., Prudential and other investment firms have a lot of resources online. Many financial planners provide a fairly generic "plan" that covers risk tolerance, asset allocation, and asset class selection, and for these types of topics, you can get a good explanation of these concepts online, as well as practical examples.

For example Prudential offers [this](http://www.preparewithpru.com/shared/content/asset-allocation-a-sound-investment-strategy.php) article on asset allocation, and another good one [here](http://www.preparewithpru.com/shared/content/what-kind-of-investor-am-i.php) on risk tolerance that includes recommended portfolios.

**A Fee Only Financial Planner**

Many "financial planners" are really captive sales agents for investment firms that sell mutual funds, and are primarily focused on selling rather than advising. If you want a professional opinion without the sales pitch, you may be interested in a Fee-Only Financial Advisor. You can find one in your area [here](http://www.napfa.org/). You could call them and ask for a review of your plan as well as any additional recommendations they might have for a flat fee. This is also a good way to get financial advice for any specific circumstances you might have that are particularly complicated.

Best of luck!

Comment: Just one thing, Ramsey might be a bit too Jesus-y for the taste of some.

Comment: @Lagerbaer - even excluding Dave's Christian outlook, his financial advice is solid